# Connectedness and components - what's wrong with my solution?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S$ be an open connected set in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $T$ be a component of $\mathbb{R}-S$. Prove that $\mathbb{R}-T$ is connected.

Definition: A real valued function $f$ which is continuous on a metric space $S$ is said to be two-valued on $S$ if $f(S)\subseteq\{0,1\}$.

Theorem: A metric space $S$ is connected iff every two-valued function on S is constant.

Attempt: Clearly $\mathbb{R}\supseteq\mathbb{R}-S\supseteq\bigcup\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}-S}T_x\supseteq T$. Now we can write $\mathbb{R}=(\mathbb{R}-T)\cup T \supseteq \mathbb{R}-T$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ and $T$ are connected, every two valued function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and $T$ is constant. Hence $f(\mathbb{R})=f((\mathbb{R}-T)\cup T)=f(T)=f(\mathbb{R}-T)$.

Since I didn't use that $S$ is open I think something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is incorrect because you don't know that every two-valued function on $\mathbb{R}-T$ can be obtained as the restriction of a two-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$; and indeed this is not the case, for example, when $T=[0,1]$, which is connected.

As a hint for (one approach to) the proof: show that an open connected set in $\mathbb{R}$ is necessarily an open interval, possibly infinite on one or both ends. What does the complement of an interval look like? What are its components? If $T$ is one of its components, what does $\mathbb{R}-T$ look like?

Comment: How can $T=[0,1]$ be not connected? Don't we know that $T$ is always connected by definition?

Comment: I said that $T=[0,1]$ *is* connected.

Comment: Oh,really sorry.

Comment: Also, $T=[0,1]$ is not something that can arise from the situation in your question. I am using it as an example to demonstrate that you cannot use your line of reasoning because it would *also* apply when $T=[0,1]$, and we know the statement is not true then; thus, this demonstrates that you must use further knowledge of how $T$ looks in the situation described in your question.

Comment: I am trying to understand why we can't obtain every two valued function on $\mathbb{R}-T$ by restriction. It is clear that the restriction of every $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}-T$ is constant but there may be other two valued functions on $\mathbb{R}-T$ which are not constant, right?

Comment: @Bedi: That's right - in the example I gave, $T=[0,1]$, we have that $\mathbb{R}-T=X\cup Y$ where $X=(-\infty,0)$ and $Y=(1,\infty)$, and the function on $\mathbb{R}-T$ defined by sending elements of $X$ to $0$ and elements of $Y$ to $1$ is a valid two-valued function on $\mathbb{R}-T$ that can't possibly be the restriction of a two-valued function on $\mathbb{R}$.